# Understanding eclipse link performance profiler output

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jpa, eclipselink

I am capturing the eclipse link profiler output, I am able to understand all the outputs, but in some cases it is showing as entityRecord:null, I am not able to understand what operation is that and it took most of the time.

Can any one suggest, why it is having null for the operation?

> Performance Monitor:1409002833438 Operation   Value (ns)
>   Counter:ClientSessionCreates  1 Counter:ConnectCalls  1
>   Counter:ReadObjectQuery   4,615
>   **Counter:ReadObjectQuery:com.test.entities.entityRecord:null**   4,615
>   Counter:UnitOfWorkCreates 1 Info:ConnectionPool:default   0
>   Info:LoginTime    Mon Aug 25 16:14:56 CDT 2014
>   Info:SessionName  file:/Users/test/workspace/testing/trunk/modules/testentity/target/test-classes/_dataSource
>   Timer:ConnectionManagement    1,021,781,000
>   Timer:JPAQuery:getMaxTime:QueryPreparation    816,000
>   Timer:JPAQuery:getMaxUpdateDate:QueryPreparation  179,043,000
>   Timer:JPAQuery:getMaxCreateDate:QueryPreparation  741,000
>   Timer:JPAQuery:getMaxTeDate:QueryPreparation  918,000
>   Timer:JPAQuery:getNon:QueryPreparation    16,889,000
>   Timer:Logging 1,028,079,606,000 Timer:ObjectBuilding  276,026,000
>   Timer:QueryPreparation    203,986,000
>   Timer:ReadObjectQuery 291,872,601,000
>   **Timer:ReadObjectQuery:com.test.entities.entityRecord:null   291,857,936,000**
>   Timer:ReadObjectQuery:com.test.entities.entityRecord:readObject:ObjectBuilding    279,030,000
>   Timer:ReadObjectQuery:com.test.entities.entityRecord:readObject:QueryPreparation  5,538,000
>   Timer:ReadObjectQuery:com.test.entities.entityRecord:readObject:RowFetch  297,910,000
>   Timer:ReadObjectQuery:com.test.entities.entityRecord:readObject:SqlGeneration 2,085,000
>   Timer:ReadObjectQuery:com.test.entities.entityRecord:readObject:SqlPrepare    170,974,000
>   Timer:ReadObjectQuery:com.test.entities.entityRecord:readObject:StatementExecute  54,530,341,000
>   Timer:RowFetch    296,488,000 Timer:SqlGeneration 2,082,000
>   Timer:SqlPrepare  171,146,000 Timer:StatementExecute  54,502,547,000